# Stored procedure that ran fine for years suddenly timing out

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have a database that's about 20 years old, constantly evolving of course. It's main function is to be the backend for a Web App. One section of said Web App stopped working, users started calling, and I was able to pinpoint that a call to a stored procedure was timing out. Everything else on the App was fine (or at least I hope so, that's part of my question. I guess I should say everything I checked was running fine.) I called the sproc from my local SQL Server Management Studio and it worked fine. I checked the server, there were no locks, blocks, or many things running.

I made the change of assigning the variables being passed in, to newly created "local" variables and changed all the places they were used in the code. Hit F5 and now it works again.

Old sample code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_sprocThatHasBeenFineForYears]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @TheId int,
    @StartDate datetime

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE TheId = @TheId AND StartDate = @StartDate
```

New Sample code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_sprocThatHasBeenFineForYears]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @TheId int,
    @StartDate datetime

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @LOCAL_TheId int = @TheId
    DECLARE @LOCAL_StartDate datetime = @StartDate

    SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE TheId = @LOCAL_TheId AND StartDate = @LOCAL_StartDate
```

My questions are:
1 - why  did this happen "out of the blue" after 10 or so years of faithful service?
2 - any way to tell if this is happening to other sprocs that users haven't discovered yet?
3 - any way to prevent this in the future?

Comment: Search for "parameter sniffing" and you'll learn the cause and that local variables are a workaround. Other options include adding an `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` query hint.

Comment: But (maybe I'll find this after researching what you told me to) do I need to be in fear that parts of my webapp are going to suddenly stop working?

Comment: Your local variable work-around will keep the lights on. It will use average density statistics for optimization instead of the actual initial parameter values. The resultant execution plan might not be the best but will be more stable instead of reusing a cached plan optimized for the initial (arbitrary) values.

Comment: @DanGuzman - I think what I'm saying is, I haven't touched this sproc in probably 10 years, did parameter sniffing suddenly make it stop?

Comment: @msimmons query plans change as the data and statistics change, hence **any** query has the potential to slow down, apparently without cause, after running for a while. Its very hard (impossible) to predict but a well designed database with good indexes should minimise the risk. However 20 years is a long time and whoever coded it back then may or may not have used good best practices.